# Regex not working in python script

Tags: python, regex, ip

for some reason when I get regex to get the number i need it returns none.
But when I run it here http://regexr.com/38n3o it works

the regex was designed to get the last number of the ip so it can be removed

```
lanip=74.125.224.72
notorm=re.search("/([1-9])\w+$/g", lanip)
```

Comment: You are using JavaScript RegEx literal notation, in Python.

Comment: Also, which number do you want?

Comment: And the RegEx you used there is `([1-9])\d+$`.

Comment: Please check all the comments.

Comment: the last number before the dot

Comment: What if the last number is `758`?

Comment: If you just want the last number before the dot `lanip.split('.')[-1]` should be enough.

Comment: The last one before the dot: `re.search(r"([1-9]\d+)$", lanip)` if you insist on a regex.

Comment: well it for internal ip adresses so it only goes to 254 im just using googles ip as a place holder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you define a regular expressions in Python. The correct way would be:

```
import re
lanip="74.125.224.72"
notorm=re.search("([1-9])\w+$", lanip)
print notorm
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10131df30>
```

You were using a javascript regex style. To read more on correct python syntax read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

If you want to match the last number of an IP use:

```
import re
lanip="74.125.224.72"
notorm=re.search("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)", lanip)
print notorm.group(4)
```

Output:

```
72
```

Regex used from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Your example did work in this scenario, but would match a lot of false positives.

Comment: can you explane how its worng its the first time ive used regex

Comment: what doese the last one output

Comment: I may have jumped the gun a bit here, it outputs the full IP but after reading your discussion above do you just want the last number?

Comment: Sorry i must of worded it worng im looking for the last number in an ip. also known as host Number in internal networks. but dont worry the first one works for what im using it for

Comment: Ive eddited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What is `lanip`'s type? That can't run.

It needs to be a string, i.e.

```
lanip = "74.125.224.72"
```

Also your RE syntax looks strange, make sure you've read the [documentation on Python's RE syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).